# Full context of the story from the verse 1.35.1, Atharvaveda

Tags: atharva-veda, daksha

As per Atharvaveda 1.35.1:

> **यदाबध्नन् दाक्षायणा हिरण्यं** शतानीकाय सुमनस्यमानाः । तत्ते बद्नाम्यायुषे वर्चसे बलाय दीर्घायुत्वाय शतशारदाय ॥१॥
> हे आयु की कामना करने वाले मनुष्य ! श्रेष्ठ विचार वाले **दक्षगोत्रीय महर्षियों ने 'शतानीक राजा' को जो हर्ष प्रदायक सुवर्ण बाँधा था।** उसी सुवर्ण को हम, आपके आयु वृद्धि के लिए, तेज और सामर्थ्य की प्राप्ति के लिए तथा सौ वर्ष की दीर्घ आयु प्राप्त कराने के लिए आपको बाँधते हैं ॥१॥
> **This Ornament of Gold which Daksha's children bound, with benevolent thoughts, on Satānïka,** This do I bind on thee for life, for glory, for long life lasting through a hundred autumns.

May I know the full context of this story highlighted in bold? Also, Is the verse talking about real "gold" or something else, as the Sanskrit verse contains the word "हिरण्यं" and not "सुवर्ण", hence is the confusion. Knowing the full story would help.

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you the whole story, but I can add a few details.

---

Firstly, the verse is in fact talking about a real gold ornament. Though *सुवर्ण* is the more common word for gold, *हिरण्यं* does mean the same thing. [This verse](https://prabhupadabooks.com/sb/3/8/30?d=1) from the Srimad Bhagavatam uses the same word.

---

The story of Satānika being given gold by the descendants of Daksha is not present in any scripture, but it seems to have been an actual historical event; as [this](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Indian_Sociology_Through_Ghurye_a_Dictio/P3uD22Ghqs4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA128&printsec=frontcover) book tells us, a Dakshayana prince actually gave the priest Satānika an unknown amount of gold during the Vedic age.

I think this is the event referred to in the Atharva Veda- in other words, the gold once given to Satānika is now being given to someone else.

---

The line after this ([AV 1.35.2/.3](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Hymns_of_the_Atharvaveda/etYoAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA41&printsec=frontcover)) explains what the gold ornament does:

> This man no fiends may conquer, no *Pisachas*, for this is the might of gods, their primal offspring. Whoever wears the gold of Daksha's children hath a long lengthened life among the living.
>
> The light, the power, the lustre of the Waters, the strength of Trees, and all their forceful vigour, We lay on him as powers abide in Indra: so let him wear this Gold and show his valour.

---

The 'hundred autumns' is a reference to what's considered the ideal length for a long human life; the [Rig Veda uses the same phrase](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/rig-veda-english-translation/d/doc840301.html))

Comment: I am aware of the next verses of 35 suktam. But i am not satisfied with hiranya as synonym for suvarna in this context. That's why asked.